# FastAPI gunicorn run scheduled job only on one worker

Tags: gunicorn, fastapi

I have a fastapi server that is running 4 workers via gunicorn.
I want to run a background / scheduled job in only one (any one) of the worker instead of all 4.
How do i ensure that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Celery to separate processes for the background job, for example:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y
```

Then, in your FastAPI application, you can call the background tasks using the delay() method. For example:

```
from tasks import sub

@app.post("/sub")
def subtract_numbers(x: int, y: int):
    result = sub.delay(x, y)
    return {"result": result.get()}
```

Finally, start the Celery worker process using the celery command. For example:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

This will start a worker process that will run the background tasks defined in the tasks module.

Or simply use gunicorn this way:

```
gunicorn yourapp:app -w 1
```